# How to change grid view filter using activeDropDownList yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, frameworks

i wanna change filter of gridview in yii2 .i want to use drop down list and check box to add filter instead of filter text box.

1)undefine Laptop model error 
2)in my code drop down list worked but showing empty list without text.(i think i wrong some thing) .help me to solve it.

here is my code

```html
   <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            //'id',
   [
   
   
                'attribute'=>'id',
    'value'=>'id',
                //'filter'=>array("1"=>"open","2"=>"in progress","3"=>"closed")
     'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'id', ArrayHelper::map(Laptop::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'laptop'),['class'=>'form-control','prompt' => 'Select Category']),
   ],
            'network',
            'technology',
            'sup_id',
            'speaker',
   'size',
   [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
 
            'template' => '{myButton}' , // the default buttons + your custom button
            'buttons' => [
                'myButton' => function($url, $model, $key) {     // render your custom button
                    return Html::a('تایید');
                }
            ]
   ],
   
     // [
           // 'class' => DataColumn::className(), // this line is optional
           /* 'attribute' => 'name',
            'format' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Name',
        ],*/
            // 'optical_drive',
             //'webcam',
            // 'touchpad',
            // 'card_reader',
            // 'ethernet',
            // 'vga',
            // 'hdmi',
            // 'usb3_ports',
            // 'usb2_ports',
            // 'usb_type_c',
            // 'thunderbolt_ports',
            // 'serial_ports',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
  
    'layout' => '{summary}{items}{pager}',
  
  
  
    ]); ?>
```

in below part what should i change to solve this problem?

```html
<?

 [
   
   
                'attribute'=>'id',
    'value'=>'id',
                //'filter'=>array("1"=>"open","2"=>"in progress","3"=>"closed")
     'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'id', ArrayHelper::map(Laptop::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'laptop'),['class'=>'form-control','prompt' => 'Select Category']),
   ],

?>
```

thanks :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try add  the realted use  clause in your view

eg if you have all the models in common\models

```
use common\models\LapTop;
```

or

```
use your_app_name\models\LapTop;
```

*assign the proper value to your_app_name*

or for basic template try

```
use app\models\LapTop;
```

and for filter try using only

```
'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(LapTop::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'laptop'),
```

Comment: Class 'yii\models\LapTop' not found

Comment: are you sure you have a class  named  LapTop in the namespace you have assigned???????

Comment: use akharin\models\Laptop; true of name.but same error

Comment: what is app scaffolding ? :( what should i send?

Comment: Is Your  application directory structure  .. .. . Anyway you are using basic template or advanced  template ?

Comment: i use basic template

Comment: answer  updated  try using    `use app\models\LapTop;`

Comment: thanks error resolved ;) .now how to show data in drop down list?
it returns empty drop down list

Comment: you should post a new question .. with only the related  part fo code and explanation  ..  is better  ..

Comment: why you must wait   90 min ??'

Comment: site allows to post just every 90 min :))

Comment: You can only post once every 90 minutes

this error

Comment: and can't change the question title and body  with a new one ??

Comment: anyway your code seems correct to me .. are you sure for the column name  in map ??

Comment: This is not fair you are potentially invalidating my right answer .. change the question once you have obtained  the right answer  for th previous is wrong ..

Comment: you should restore  the question to the original  version ..  and post a new one for your new question  ..

Comment: i wanted to do that but was impossible :(

Comment: and for the firts question you  should add . an explaition for the firts question too ..

Comment: i added first question too :)

Comment: thanks..i think your answer and my code works!!!

but a problem is not showing them.it just shows empty fields.and just number of them are true without value in it..and when i click not working....what s wrong with it?

Comment: are you sure you have really the values  in you db  and the columns name match with the field name ( remember that are case sensitive)

Comment: just for debug  .. using literals values as  array("1"=>"open","2"=>"in progress","3"=>"closed") .. work ? .. id work .. then is a matching problem .. let me know

Comment: that s show when manually set value . but now from database just work truely and no showing its values

Comment: I repeat  .. then you must check if the column you are in as array match with the column names .. evetually  update your question and add your LapTop model code

Comment: that works truely. but i just want to show value of it.for example if we have 3 different laptop.it shows 3 of them and filtering truely.just not showing 1,2,3
but their fields are true

Comment: if we enter incorrect name not working at all but now working

Comment: <option value="1"></option> shows this type in..and client can not see value.how to fix it to show to client?

Answer (score 1):

If you use PhpStorm you can delete this code "Laptop::find()"
after you type in this place word "Laptop"  - PhpStorm added dropdown - from this dropdown you should choice "location of your Laptopclass",

after it - in code your word "Laptop" will be replaced by something like it -"common\models\LapTop::find()"

Example: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/EVvBKDB1NNQ/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: if you commented code with using "Laptop class" - do you get the same error or not ? You need to know line that generate your error.

Comment: thank you dude.it resolves at former answer..post updated :)))